# How can I remove hyperlink in poi 3.8?

Tags: apache-poi

I have some problem with reading an excel file contains hyperlink text in poi.

Data is like that(excel file):
|1| **type** | **category** | **job_type** | **position** | **name** | **email**
|2| Test    | developer | parttime  | manager | hong    | asdf##@dsaf.com(*hyperlink*)
|3| Test    | developer | parttime  | manager | asde | test@mail.com(*hyperlink*)
|4| Test    | developer | parttime  | manager | asde | aaaaaaa(*non-hyperlink*)

To create workbook object, I use `WorkbookFactory.create(InputStream inp)` method.
Codes are here:

```java
public POIExcelImport(String name, InputStream inputStream) throws ExcelImportException {
    super(name, null);
    try {

        logger.debug("before work : {}", this.workbook);

        this.workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);// exception 

    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        throw new ExcelImportException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ExcelImportException(e);
    } 

    if(XSSFWorkbook.class.isAssignableFrom(workbook.getClass()))
        this.type = ExcelFileType.XLSX;
    else
        this.type = ExcelFileType.XLS;
}
```

When I call `create` method, Exception was thrown.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The hyperlink for cell F2 references relation rId1, but that didn't exist!
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFHyperlink.<init>(XSSFHyperlink.java:71) ~[poi-ooxml-3.8.jar:3.8]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.initHyperlinks(XSSFSheet.java:204) ~[poi-ooxml-3.8.jar:3.8]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:157) ~[poi-ooxml-3.8.jar:3.8]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:129) ~[poi-ooxml-3.8.jar:3.8]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:269) ~[poi-ooxml-3.8.jar:3.8]
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159) ~[poi-ooxml-3.8.jar:3.8]
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:183) ~[poi-ooxml-3.8.jar:3.8]
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:73) ~[poi-ooxml-3.8.jar:3.8]
at dreaminfra.ipams.common.excel.poi.POIExcelImport.<init>(POIExcelImport.java:49) ~[ipams-core-1.0.0.jar:na]
```

I want to remove hyperlink, but there are only issues about to create hyperlink.
I don't have idea, is there any idea?

Comment: I update apache-poi version from 3.8 to 3.9, and problem is solved.

Comment: How did you do it?  Just set the HyperLink for the HSSFCell to `null`?  I'm over in NPOI having the same problem.

Comment: @ebyrob Sorry, I can't remember how I did.

Comment: It looks like nulling and zeroing all values in the hyperlink will remove it.  (Instead of setting cell's hyperlink value to null, which throws an exception.)

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work on my system:

```
ICell oCell = workbook.GetSheetAt(0).GetRow(0).GetCell(0);
IHyperlink oLink = oCell.Hyperlink;
oLink.setFirstRow(0);
oLink.setLastRow(0);
oLink.setFirstColumn(0);
oLink.setLastColumn(0);
oLink.setLabel(null);
oLink.setAddress("");
```

Note: I'm primarily working with NPOI (C# version) not POI (Java version), but it seems to work the same.  Also, be sure to keep the `.setAddress()` last.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately this seems to cause documents that cannot be saved by Excel for some reason.  (excel detects corruption on save)  So it doesn't actually work in practice, looks like someone will have to patch the NPOI repository for this one.