# How to remove Hyperlink and images in word document?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, extractor

I have tried to remove Hyperlink and image in word document using `Apache POI`?
this is my code

```
String text;
for (String coba : xw.getParagraphText()) {
    text = xw.stripFields(coba);
    text = coba.replaceAll("\\cM?\r?\n", "");
    sb.append(text);
}
```

But can't get clear text.

Answer (score 0):

First, You should update your apache-poi version.

related link:

[How can I remove hyperlink in poi 3.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699049/how-can-i-remove-hyperlink-in-poi-3-8)

Comment: that is example for Excel document, i hope i can clear text *.doc or *.docx, and i have upgrade version poi 3.8